# How to convert dataframe to keras model input layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Okay, I have a trained keras model and am trying to make predictions. The layers are shown here
[image: Model Layers]

For the D1 Input layer, I have a dataframe, `X_test_soc` which has shape 2203,16. When I used that as my model input I got
ValueError: Input 3 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 16), found shape=(None, 0)
Some research said I should convert to an array, so I first did
`X_test_soc_array =  X_test_soc.to_num`
This gave me an array of shape 2203,16, but I got the error

ValueError: Input 3 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 16), found shape=(None, 0)
Finally, I tried reshaping the array as follows:

`X_test_soc_array.reshape((2203, 16))`
Here I got this error

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (2203,16)

Can anyone give me pointers on how to convert my dataframe to an appropriately sized array?

I have tried converting the dataframe to an array and reshaping that array, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Your problem is that the data has shape 0, which is completely unrelated to Keras.

Comment: So the model keeps saying. Apologies for being unfamiliar with the process as I'm unfortunately picking up for a data scientist who left abruptly. Why does it have shape 0 when the array says it has shape 2203,16

Comment: Normally in pandas (I assume it's pandas as you mentioned "dataframe"), you use `dataframe.values` to get the numpy array from the dataframe. Why it says it has shape 0, we can't say without seeing the code.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up converting to an array and then transposing twice and that did it. But you know, it doesn't feel like a GREAT answer, but it does work.